# Is it possible to get a short term housing loan in India?

Tags: india, loans

Suppose I want to pay for a house with my own funds expect that they are stuck in deposits that I can't redeem immediately. Is there any way I can get say a 40 lakh loan for a tenure of 1 year?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can get a Loan against security(or colletral) for any amount for whatever duration.

If you already have FD, you can ask your bank to mark a lien on the FD's and give you a loan. More better open an current account with Over Draft limit. The rate charged is typically around 1 to 1.5% more than the FD rate. As it would be a current account, you will only be charged to the extent you use the account.

You can also get similar facility for your car or any other such assets, Gold for example, shares from